# Possible to to autofill column with formulas with =isoweeknum & =arrayformula

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, week-number

I've been using the =arrayformula in some cases to autofill an entire column with calculations. Now I just discovered that this is not working with every formula. At this moment I want to add the weeknumber of a specific date in a seperate column. Since there is new data being added to the sheet I don't constantly want to add new formulas in the column manually so thats the reason I'm trying it with an ARRAYFORMULA but sadly it is not working.

Wanted to try it with this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISOWEEKNUM(B2), ISOWEEKNUM(INT(B2)), "" ))
```

Or this:

```
=arrayformula(isoweeknum(B6))
```

Does anyone know how I can automatics add formulas in column (H) that will convert a date to weeknums?

Thank you in advance!

KR, Sami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,IF(ISOWEEKNUM(B2:B), ISOWEEKNUM(INT(B2:B)), )))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! This is working. Do you know why this works and my formula doesn't? I guess I can learn from it :). Thanks!

Comment: @SamiChouchane you had it you just didn't include range B2:B instead you left it at B2 which will not populate the column down the line